# Camel Migration 2.x to 4.x: Replace class Namespaces

Tags: apache-camel

I have to migrate a camel route from version 2.x to 4.x.

The route uses the class org.apache.camel.builder.xml.Namespaces. This class has been gone with Camel 3. Unfortunalety the Camel migration guide does not describe, how to replace this class.

I hope someone has an idea how I can resolve this in Camel 4.Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The `Namespaces` class was moved in Camel 3.x due to some internal refactoring of the Camel core.

In Camel 3.x & 4.x, the class can now be found at `org.apache.camel.support.builder.Namespaces`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I had also found the class. However, the code seems to have changed. In my route, the "xpath" function of the Namespaces class is used. This function no longer exists in Camel 4.

Do you know where the function was moved to?